# Python 3 - Remove unnecessary results on web scraping

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I have an issue on web scraping for this particular page for some kind of business with more than one type of business arrive as result. These instructions are working fine if business belongs to just one category only (Pharmacy on the example):

```html
# import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = ['http://www.paginasamarillas.com.ar/buscar/q/farmacia/p-1/']
print (quote_page)

data = []
 
for pg in quote_page:
 page = urlopen(pg)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

 # Search company name and business type
 nombreBox = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'t1 business-name', 'itemprop':'name'})
 tipoBox = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'business-categories'})
 
 # Clean Results
 nombre = nombreBox.text.strip()
 tipo = tipoBox.text.strip()
 # tipo = tipo.split(" ")[0] # Tried with split and print only first word but is not working

 
 # Record results on array
 data.append((nombre, tipo))
 print (nombre, tipo)
```

```
#####################  RESULTS #######################

['http://www.paginasamarillas.com.ar/buscar/q/farmacia/p-1/']
Farmacia Iphais Farmacias
________^______ ____^____
 Company Name    BZ type
######################################################
```

But some business belong to more than just one category and came with a "more+" link with more details as below results:

```
#####################  RESULTS #######################

['http://www.paginasamarillas.com.ar/buscar/q/farmacia/p-1/'] 
Farmacia Zimerman Farmacias  #Starting here there are more business kind I don´t want it

 Perfumerias                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             mas +                                                                                                                   menos -     

    ######################################################
```

I just want to keep first kind of business or category instead of multiple and discard all the results under "more +" link.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

Within the business-categories element, there is an "a" tag that stores the first characteristic. You can search within the tipoBox for this element and then just print that out.

```
tipoBox = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'business-categories'})
first_element = tipoBox.find('a')
```

I noticed that currently your program would only print the first listing on the website. Assuming that you want to loop through all the listings on the website here is how I rewrote your program to obtain the name of the establishment and the first description:

```
  for pg in quote_page:
    page = urlopen(pg)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    business = soup.find('ul', class_='businesses')
    links = business.find_all('li', class_='business')

    data = []
    for link in links:
        nombreBox = link.find('div', attrs={'class':'t1 business-name', 'itemprop':'name'})
        category = link.find('div', attrs={'class':'business-categories'})
        first_element = category.find('a')
        data.append((nombreBox.text.strip(), first_element.text.strip()))

    return data
```